# WebApi 6 response wrapper

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a .net 5 webapi and I'd like to wrap all my response objects in a meta data object. My question is if a Middleware is the right way to go or if I can make a DelegatingHandler?
I cannot figure out how to do it using a Middleware, if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to send down?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an OwinMiddleware and change the response there, if you want.

For example:

```
public class WrapMyAnswersMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public WrapMyAnswersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {          
        await _next.Invoke(context);

        // change the context here
    }
}
```

and you can activate it like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<WrapMyAnswersMiddleware>();
}
```

Hope it helps :)